# Formation of waves in different medium

Tags: waves

When a stone is thrown into the water then transverse waves are formed but it is said that longitudinal waves can travel through any medium solid , liquid and gases then why a longitudinal wave does not form in water when a stone is thrown.

Comment: Have a look at this video - [Ripples in a pond](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dESm6VjfSNs) - which shows the two types of waves formed when a stone is thrown into a pond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Longitudinal waves are formed, but the thing is that you cannot see a longitudinal wave even in water.
The sound produced in water, due to the stone is a longitudinal wave only, the disturbance on the surface however is a transverse wave only.